# Updating values being pulled from database using lou jquery multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, multi-select

I am using [lou's multiselect.js](http://loudev.com/) to update selected values that were previously stored in the database. I am getting the selected values from the database, however it's in the wrong column, as shown below. I would like to retrieve the values from the database that weren't selected(to be on the lef) along with those that have already been selected(to be on the right).

---

The list of items below(on the left) were already selected items being brought back from the database, but they should be under the **Selected Product Types** column instead. And then under **Available Product Types** the list of items that have not been selected as yet should be shown.

[image]

---

**HTML**

*This gets the previously selected products from the database as shown in the picture above*

```
<select multiple id="product-multi-select" name="product-multi-select" ng-model="input_doc_type.product" required>
    @foreach($inputDocData[0]->product as $data)
    <option value="{{$data->id}}" selected>{{$data->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

---

**JQuery**

*Gets all the products*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("#product-multi-select").multiSelect({
        selectableHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Available Product Types</div>",
        selectionHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Selected Product Types</div>"
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var products = [];

        $.get('/admin/products/all-products', function(data, response) {
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                products.push(value.name);
            });
            $("#product-multi-select").multiSelect('select', products);
            $(".ms-container").append('<i class="glyph-icon icon-exchange"></i>');
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to go about using this. Any assistance with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I had to add an extra function in the js file which supports getting recognizing selected values (shown below). It's a replica of the *addOption* function that came with the file, but with one slight update.

**multiselect.js**

```
'selectedAddOption' : function(options){
        var that = this;

        if (options.value) options = [options];
        $.each(options, function(index, option){
            if (option.value && that.$element.find("option[value='"+option.value+"']").length === 0){
                var $option = $('<option value="'+option.value+'" selected>'+option.text+'</option>'),
                    index = parseInt((typeof option.index === 'undefined' ? that.$element.children().length : option.index)),
                    $container = option.nested == undefined ? that.$element : $("optgroup[label='"+option.nested+"']")

                $option.insertAt(index, $container);
                that.generateLisFromOption($option.get(0), index, option.nested);
            }
        })
    },
```

---

After adding that piece of code to the js file. I then made a request from the database which pulled in all unused products and then dynamically them to the *select* (shown below). This was added over on the *Available Product Types* side

```
// retrieve all products
        $.get('/admin/products/all-products', function(data, response) {
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                $('#product-multi-select').multiSelect('addOption', { value: value.id, text: value.name, index: 0 });
            });
            $("#product-multi-select").multiSelect('refresh');
            $(".ms-container").append('<i class="glyph-icon icon-exchange"></i>');
        });
```

---

Finally, I then made another request which pulled in all products that were already selected, and this utlilized the *selectedAddOption* which I added to the js file. And these were then also added to the select box, over on the *Selected Product Types* side

```
// retrieve all selected products
        <?php foreach ($inputDocData[0]->product as $val) { ?>
            $('#product-multi-select').multiSelect('selectedAddOption', { value: <?php echo $val->id; ?>, text: '<?php echo $val->name; ?>', index: 0 });
        <?php } ?>
        $("#product-multi-select").multiSelect('refresh');
        $(".ms-container").append('<i class="glyph-icon icon-exchange"></i>');
```

---

There are no  present because they are dynamically added using jquery.

```
select multiple id="product-multi-select" name="product-multi-select[]" ng-model="input_doc_type.product" required></select>
```

---

The code did what it was supposed to do and there were no duplication of items in the list.

I hope this may become helpful to someone else.